# Rails Activerecord Reverse Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have models:

```
class Materialtitle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :edocs
end

class Edoc < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :materialtitles
end
```

I may do `Materialtitle.find(2).edocs`.
I would like to do something like `Edoc.find(10).materialtitles`. But It returns **nil**.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is many-to-one then it should be `belongs_to :materialtitle` (singular) and your DSL should look like:

```
 Edoc.includes(:materialtitle).find(10).materialtitle
```